# What is the purpose of opening this package in March?

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-1

**Spoilers for the Pandemic Legacy Season 1 Legacy Deck for the beginning of March below.**

---

According to the legacy deck in Pandemic Legacy Season 1, in the beginning of March, you are instructed to open box 5.

I opened all the other packages that you are also instructed to open, and all of them related to

> military base construction

but I cannot figure out for the life of me what the items within box 5 are for.  Was this a misprint and they will become useful later, or did I miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should have opened *door* 5, not box 5. You can tape box 5 back up and continue with the game with no ill effects, especially as the meaning of the contents of box 5 is not apparent to you at this time.

From what I remember, when you are instructed to open a box (or package as the game refers to it), it will specifically say "Open Package #". Numbers in circles are doors to be opened, and letters in circles are rules to be opened (same mechanism as doors).

According to [this thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1500066/full-game-spoilers-numbered-contents-all-legacy-co), the contents of door 5 is

> Three additional scars, so you're not missing anything vital

Comment: Oh damn I feel dumb.  But you are right, and I should be confused by what was in package 5.  And IIRC, one of the things I opened had the instruction to open the page that contained all the stuff behind the spoiler.  So does this mean there's a good chance I'm missing something then?  Since I didn't open door 5?

Comment: @DenisS edited my answer to include the contents of door 5

Comment: Accepted and upvoted.  Next time we play I'll know to fix it.